# Remove caption shortcode form category archives - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, caption, wp-list-categories

I have some strange problem in wordpress

How can i remove this [caption] short code for my category archive list 
http://start.neomedia.info/category/sport/

This caption works great in one article 
http://start.neomedia.info/diego-lopez-jestem-lepszy-niz-casillas/
but not on list it's appear and thats really strange.

what should i add in code ? ( a replace function ?)

I am not talking about CSS solution because this will not work.

Can someone help ?

Answer (score 0):

Although you didn't provide any code, I assume that you are using [`the_excerpt`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) function in your category page.

`Caption` is a shortcode, and by default shortcodes doesn't work in the excerpt. If you don't specify an excerpt for your post and let WordPress deal with it automatically, it will strip the caption and the image completely. As it is mentioned in the docs:

> An auto-generated excerpt will also have all shortcodes and tags
>   removed.

Therefore, I assume that you entered manually the excerpt while creating the post, and copied and pasted there the caption code. That will prevent WordPress from removing it automatically, but it will treat it as normal text, and not a caption.

To bypass this issue, you can add the following filter into your functions.php file, which will force the caption (and any other shortcodes) to be processed:

`add_filter('the_excerpt', 'do_shortcode');`

Please note that as far as I know the above will work only with manually added excerpts; it will not affect the automatically generated ones, where the shortcodes & tags will continue to be ignored.